# Is there a way to achieve a gridview with different size child widgets like this?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, photo-gallery

I am developing a app screen from flutter and having problem with designing this design and looping the data from database. Is there anyone who created a design like this in flutter please suggest me a way.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      itemCount: 16,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Text('$index'),//your photo in place of this child
),
      staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>StaggeredTile.count(index%7==0?2:1,index%7==0?2:1,),
      mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
      crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
    )
```

Comment: Thank you soo much Deepak. You saved my day.

Comment: Am Happy, That i was able to help you :)